# Latest iOS 11.2 - background geolocation not working.

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, gps, ios11

When I put my app in the background on the phone, I'm not able to retrieve the GPS coordinates. This changed when I converted my phone from 10.2 to 11.2. I've done a few tests where I've been able to nail down that it's not the hardware and it has to be some sort of configuration on my phone or the software version. Also to note - when I'm trying to retrieve the background GPS I'm using the background geolocation plugin that ionic provides as I am using an Ionic App. Thanks